# MySQL insert data into table with foreign keys that are no the primary key of the reference table

Tags: mysql, reference, insert, foreign-keys

I have a table song that contains the artistname and genre as a foreign key, but they are not the primary keys in the artist and genre tables. I am hoping to enter the data into the song table and auto populate in the other two tables, unless my logic is wrong. So this is the song table:

```
 CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project`.`song` (
`idsong` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`artistname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`title` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`genre` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`year` INT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`lyrics` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`url` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`idsong`) ,
INDEX `title` (`title` ASC) ,
INDEX `genre_idx` (`genre` ASC) ,
INDEX `artistname_idx` (`artistname` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `genre`
FOREIGN KEY (`genre` )
REFERENCES `project`.`genres` (`genre` )
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `artistname`
FOREIGN KEY (`artistname` )
REFERENCES `project`.`artist` (`artistname` )
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

and the other two tables:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project`.`genres` (
`genre` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`genre`) )
 ENGINE = InnoDB

 CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project`.`artist` (
`idartist` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`artistname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`bio` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`idartist`) ,
INDEX `artistname` (`artistname` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

This is my query that is not working:

```
INSERT INTO song (artist, title, genre, year, lyrics, url)
    VALUES
    ('Jason Aldean', 'Night Train', 'Country', '2012', 'This is the song lyrics', '9ADpkg1dkDU');
```

Any ideas what's wrong? I'm a newbie so i'm sure it is the user :)

Answer (score 1):

This will not work the way you think: A foreign key constraint can do `ON DELETE CASCADE` and `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, but it can not do something like `ON INSERT CASCADE`.

What you need is a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on the song table, that will populate the referenced tables if necessary.

Comment: So how do I add trigger? I made the model with MySQL Workbench that imports it into mysql server directly. Or should I break the query into separate ones for each table? Thanks!

Comment: You will need to research triggers from the MySQL docs, it is quite easy, just think of a stored procedure that is called for every new row. If you can break up your query, this will sort of work also, but you will run into trouble on concurrency issues: Think of two scripts inserting the same new artist at the same time.

Comment: How can I set up a trigger to add the artistname in the artist table first if it does not exit when insert values in the songs table?

Comment: In the Trigger you would run something like `INSERT IGNORE INTO artist ...` - this makes sure, your artist row exists. Since it is a `BEFORE INSERT` Trigger, the newly created row can then referenced by the main part of the query to insert into song